# Resize table view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, resize

I'm searching for a way to have a UITableViewController with a UITableView at the top and a UIPickerView bellow (with fix position).

I've found a solution for fixing the picker with the code bellow:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    _picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    _picker.dataSource = self;
    _picker.delegate = self;

    // Add the picker to the superview so that it will be fixed
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:_picker];

    CGRect pickerFrame = _picker.frame;
    pickerFrame.origin.y = self.tableView.frame.size.height - 29 - pickerFrame.size.height;

    _picker.frame = pickerFrame;

    CGRect tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame;
    tableViewFrame.size.height = 215;

    self.tableView.frame = tableViewFrame;

    [_picker release];
}
```

The problem is with the tableview, it seems resizing doesn't work so I can't see all results .

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Will it work if you make your controller a UIViewController instead of a UITableViewController and then manually add the UITableView?

Comment: That's the solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a `UIViewController` subclass instead of `UITableViewController` to manage a table view if the view to be managed is composed of multiple subviews, one of which is a table view. You can add a `UITableView` subview and make your controller implement `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols.

The default behavior of the `UITableViewController` class is to make the table view fill the screen between the navigation bar and the tab bar (if either are present).

From [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html):

> **Note:** You should use a
> UIViewController subclass rather than
> a subclass of UITableViewController to
> manage a table view if the view to be
> managed is composed of multiple
> subviews, one of which is a table
> view. The default behavior of the
> UITableViewController class is to make
> the table view fill the screen between
> the navigation bar and the tab bar (if
> either are present).
>
> If you decide to
> use a UIViewController subclass rather
> than a subclass of
> UITableViewController to manage a
> table view, you should perform a
> couple of the tasks mentioned above to
> conform to the human-interface
> guidelines. To clear any selection in
> the table view before it’s displayed,
> implement the viewWillAppear: method
> to clear the selected row (if any) by
> calling deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:.
> After the table view has been
> displayed, you should flash the scroll
> view’s scroll indicators by sending a
> flashScrollIndicators message to the
> table view; you can do this in an
> override of the viewDidAppear: method
> of UIViewController.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's the solution.